# I want to insert documents using upsert in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am fetching data from an external api and I want to insert multiple records if they are not already there . I am creating an array of objects like this :

```
data=[
  {
    match_id: 212167781,
    player1Id: 129753806,
    player2Id: 129753811,
    player1Details: '5f070c8f79f62c00042b0cd8',
    player2Details: '5f3267fe6a0f891b3604b999'
  },
  {
    match_id: 212167782,
    player1Id: 129753799,
    player2Id: null,
    player1Details: '5f070ade79f62c00042b0cd6'
  }
]
```

Now for instance if the second record is not already present then I want it to be inserted and I have tried upsert but nothing happens . Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a simple loop and `Model.findOneAndUpdate` in combination with the [upsert option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#upsert):

```
async function upsertMany(data) {

   for(const entry of data) {
      await YourModel.findOneAndUpdate(entry, entry, { upsert: true });
   }

}

// call this with your data-array
await upsertMany(data);
```